# Decimal or Point Data Type for storing Geo location data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, spatial

I want to store Geo location for each Address in my MySQL(Innodb) "tblAddress" table and I think I have 2 Options:

```
1) 2 columns for Each Address:
Latitude DECIMAL(10, 8), 
Longitude DECIMAL(11, 8)

2) One Column for Each Address:
GeoLocation POINT
```

My program need to find all Address that fall under 1 Kilometer Radius from current Location (Mobile Client).

Also below command does not work for me, not sure what I need to have for this.

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX GeoLocation ON tblAddress (GeoLocation);
```

So what is the suggested approach to store data for faster calculation and retrieval here. Please advise.

Answer (score 12):

You could use MySQL's [spatial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html) extensions with GIS.

In a [code example from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1) displaying points on a map, they state:

> When you create the MySQL table, you want to pay particular attention
>   to the lat and lng attributes. With the current zoom capabilities of
>   Google Maps, you should only need 6 digits of precision after the
>   decimal.
>
> To keep the storage space required for our table at a minimum, you can
>   specify that the lat and lng attributes are floats of size (10,6).
>   That will let the fields store 6 digits after the decimal, plus up to
>   4 digits before the decimal, e.g. -123.456789 degrees I wouldn't worry
>   about performance differences between numeric types. Decent indices
>   will have a far greater effect.

You could also try `DECIMAL` as @[gandaliter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places) suggest.

> `DECIMAL` is the MySQL data-type for
>   exact arithmetic. Unlike `FLOAT` its precision is fixed for any size of
>   number, so by using it instead of `FLOAT` you might avoid precision
>   errors when doing some calculations. If you were just storing and
>   retrieving the numbers without calculation then in practice `FLOAT`
>   would be safe, although there's no harm in using `DECIMAL`. With
>   calculations `FLOAT` is still mostly ok, but to be absolutely sure of
>   8d.p. precision you should use `DECIMAL`.
>
> Latitudes range from -90 to +90 (degrees), so `DECIMAL(10,8)` is ok for
>   that, but longitudes range from -180 to +180 (degrees) so you need
>   `DECIMAL(11,8)`. The first number is the total number of digits stored,
>   and the second is the number after the decimal point.
>   In short: `lat DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL, lng DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL`
>   [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html) explains how MySQL works with floating-point data-types.

Related information:

- [MySQL and GIS, GeoIP: FAQs, How-To, Articles, Blogs](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,184702,184702#msg-184702)
- [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1)
- [Using the new spatial functions in MySQL 5.6 for geo-enabled applications](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)

Comment: Thank you @oNare for your detail explanation and references.   
I did seen the suggestion by gandaliter in the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places). I have also seen the suggestion by ypercube here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560147/datatype-to-store-longitude-latitude-in-mysql).